# Delete rows in ndarray where sum of multiple indexes is 0

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

So I have a very large two-dimensional numpy array such as:

```
array([[ 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 9, 0],
       [ 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1],
       [ 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 8, 3],
       [ 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 6, 4, 4],
       ...,
       [ 6, 5, 6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5]])
```

I would like to quickly remove each row of the array where `np.sum(row[2:5]) == 0`

The only way I can think to do this is with for loops, but that takes very long when there are millions of rows. Additionally, this needs to be constrained to Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean expressions can be used as an index. You can use them to mask the array.

```
inputarray = array([[ 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 9, 0],
                    [ 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1],
                    [ 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 8, 3],
                    [ 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 6, 4, 4],
                    ...,
                    [ 6, 5, 6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5]])

mask = numpy.sum(inputarray[:,2:5], axis=1) != 0
result = inputarray[mask,:]
```

What this is doing:

- `inputarray[:, 2:5]` selects all the columns you want to sum over
- `axis=1` means we're doing the sum on the columns
- We want to **keep** the rows where the sum **is not** zero
- The mask is used as a row index and selects the rows where the boolean expression is `True`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use `numpy.apply_along_axis` to calculate the sums and cast it as a bool, and use that for your index:

```
my_arr = np.array([[ 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 9, 0],
       [ 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1],
       [ 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 8, 3],
       [ 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 6, 4, 4],])
my_arr[np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: bool(sum(x[2:5])), 1, my_arr)]

array([[2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1],
       [1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 8, 3]])
```

We just cast the sum too a bool since any number that's not 0 is going to be `True`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a
array([[2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 9, 0],
       [2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1],
       [1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 8, 3],
       [0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 6, 4, 4],
       [6, 5, 6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5]])
```

You are interested in columns 2 through five

```
>>> a[:,2:5]
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [4, 3, 2],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [6, 0, 0]])
>>> b = a[:,2:5]
```

You want to find the sum of those columns in each row

```
>>> sum_ = b.sum(1)
>>> sum_
array([0, 1, 9, 0, 6])
```

These are the rows that meet your criteria

```
>>> sum_ != 0
array([False,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> keep = sum_ != 0
```

Use [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) to select those rows

```
>>> a[keep, :]
array([[2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1],
       [1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 8, 3],
       [6, 5, 6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5]])
>>>
```